# Using a graph to solve the "Water in buckets" brain teaser

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given two initially empty buckets A and B, with capacities of m litres
and n litres, respectively, the goal is to measure exactly k litres of water using these two buckets. Assume that m, n and k are positive integers and that k <= max(m, n). We want to achieve this goal by performing a sequence of moves until one of the buckets has exactly k litres of water. Each move can be one of the following:

- Fill a bucket until it's full.
- Empty a bucket.
- Use the water in one bucket to fill the other until one of the buckets is full or empty.

Devise an algorithm BucketMeasure(m, n, k), which takes m, n and k as inputs and outputs a sequence of moves that results in one bucket (it does not matter which one) having exactly k litres of water. The number of moves in the returned sequence must be the smallest possible number of moves that are needed to achieve the goal. If it is impossible to measure k litres of water using the two buckets, the algorithm returns NIL.

Questions:

1. How do you construct a graph for solving this problem? Describe the vertices and edges in your graph clearly and precisely.
2. How does your algorithm work? Give a detailed description and justify its correctness.
3. Analyse the worst-case runtime of your algorithm.

---

I'm trying to work out a solution. So far I have the following. There seem to be only 6 possible choices that can be made at any given moment.

1. Fill A
2. Fill B
3. Empty A
4. Empty B
5. Fill A with B until it's full or A is empty
6. Fill B with A until it's full or B is empty

This is where the tricky part comes in, making the graph. My initial thought was to make each node have an attribute for the amount of water in each bucket. For instance, the first node can be N(0/m, 0/n). Which indicates that it has two empty buckets.

Let's say that the capacities of m and n are 7 and 4 respectively. So the possible combination of nodes in the graph is:

A: 0/7, 1/7, ... , 7/7

B: 0/4, 1/4, ... , 4/4

Total number: (m+1)(n+1)

This is where I got stuck. How do I proceed? Do I make each node have 6 edges to show the possible choices the user can make?

Comment: Hello, Ryan - without a third bucket to hold "difference", you might be overthinking the problem.  Given the parameters given - there are only 3 possible solutions - m, n and m-n. (assuming m>n).  The key is that you either empty or fill - no partials.  A filled (m), B filled (n), or  B filled from A (m-n left in A).  Oh - and a fourth (empty) bucket, of course.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: @John with buckets of size A=5 and B=4, one can make 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. For example to make 2: fill A (5-0), pour A into B (1-4), empty B (1-0), pour A into B (0-1), fill A (5-1), pour A into B (2-4).

Comment: @Paul - thank you, my apologies, I actually realized the exponential (m-n), later that night, but was unable to correct myself. I'd consider deleting, but it should serve as a warning to think thoroughly before commenting (a reminder to myself, at least)

Answer (score 1):

> Do I make each node have 6 edges to show the possible choices the user can make?

Pretty much. You can keep a dictionary of `(n,m) -> node` relations.

1. Create a new node and a `(0,0)` entry for it.
2. Put `(0,0)` pair in a `to process` queue.
3. Take a pair X from `to process` queue.
4. Create Y for every valid move.
5. For each Y

   - if it exists in the dictionary, ignore it
   - if it doesn't, create a new node, create a X-Y link, and put the new pair corresponding to Y in the `to process` queue
6. Go back to 3

Now you can look through the keys of your dictionary to see which nodes solve your issue. You can use some standard graph path search to find your way to `(0,0)`.

Possible improvements:

- keep another dictionary of single value from each pair -> list of pairs which contain that number; this way you don't have to iterate the whole dictionary again to find your answers

Comment: What would be the run-time efficiency of this? If I had really large m and n values wouldn't the graph get extremely dense

Comment: @RyanSmith Constructing the graph: `O(N+M)` where `N`/`M` are the bucket sizes. That's assuming dictionary inserts and lookups are also `O(N+M)`. The lookup of the path to take depends on what algorithm you use.

Comment: I was thinking of doing a BFS

Comment: Isn't it O(N*M)? First bucket can have N values and 2nd bucket M values. Also (1,0) isn't the same as (0,1) if we have N=5 and M=6, the former allows us to reach 2 in 2 moves with (1,6), (5,2), but the latter takes 3 moves.

Comment: @maraca Good point, I forgot about the different sizes. That indeed makes it `O(N*M)`.

Comment: You can use Dijkstra's algorithm or A*.